# Align horizontal cdots in an alignat environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, alignat

I am using `alignat` environment to align a set of equations which practically describe the same thing, but for different quantities. Therefore I decided to skip the common things and replace them with `\cdots`, however I don't seem to be able to align them in the center.

[image]

Any idea to center the dots?

A sample code follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{4}
  &\sigma(E) &=& \vec{\sigma(E)} = \big\{\sigma(E_1), \sigma(E_2), \cdots, \sigma(E_n)\big\} &=&  \big\{\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \cdots, \sigma_n\big\}&\\
 &C(E) &=&{\cdots}&=&  \big\{C_1, C_2, \cdots, C_n\big\}&\\
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: not directly releated, but don't use `&=&` in AMS environments, just `&=`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : Thank you very much for your comment and advice! But why not?

Comment: it doesn't work, as you see in the image you posted the `=` has lost its relation spacing as the `&=&` has made it lose the expression on the right.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, I see! Thank you very much for the explanation!

Comment: Are you sure about `\vec{\sigma(E)}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can result to low level TeX with the `\omit` to break out of the current formatting:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \sigma(E) &={}& \vec{\sigma(E)}
  = \bigl\{\sigma(E_1), \sigma(E_2), \dots, \sigma(E_n)\bigr\}
  &= \bigl\{\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \dots, \sigma_n\bigr\}\\
  C(E) &={}&\omit\hfill$\cdots$\hfill
  &= \bigl\{C_1, C_2, \dots, C_n\bigr\}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Note I have also added groups `{}` to get correct spacing at the equals signs, and use `\bigl...\bigr` instead of `\big`.  Also between commas you should just use `\dots` (or `\dotsc`).

Be careful here with the use of the ampersands `&`.  In `alignat`, the alignment is implicitly `rlrl...` with the first group right aligned, the second left aligned, etc.

Answer (score 3):

A solution with the `eqparbox` package. Note that 2 alignment columns are enough.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \sigma(E) &= {}& \eqmathbox{\vec{\sigma(E)} = \big\{\sigma(E_1), \sigma(E_2), \cdots, \sigma(E_n)\big\}} &= \big\{\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \cdots, \sigma_n\big\}\\
 C(E) &= {}& \eqmathbox{\cdots\cdots}&= \big\{C_1, C_2, \cdots, C_n\big\}\\
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`array` is not made for aligning equations, but in this case, with a couple of tricks (`@{}` and `{}` where we want a correct spacing after/before the first/last equal sign), it may be convenient.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{r@{}c@{}l}
  \sigma(E) ={} & \vec{\sigma(E)} = \big\{\sigma(E_1), \sigma(E_2), \cdots, \sigma(E_n)\big\} & {}= \big\{\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \cdots, \sigma_n\big\}\\
 C(E) ={} &\cdots& {}=  \big\{C_1, C_2, \cdots, C_n\big\}\\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]